# How to check provider to see if HTTP data is ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am using the ionic beta framework for mobile development which uses Angular2 so I think this is more of an Angular2 question as it is more in regards to using a provider for HTTP calls.

My app starts at app.js. In this file I call my provider which makes an HTTP call to get some information in the background. While this is happening the user goes away from app.js and goes to another page page.js. In the background the http call is still being made and hasent completed. The page should display the data coming from the provider, but the data is not ready yet. I am new to Angular and am unsure how to handle this type of situation. From my page how can I call my provider, check the status of the call (see if the data is ready, if an error occurred, or if there has been a call made at all), and get the data if it is ready?

**My app.js:**

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';
import {FacebookFriends} from './providers/facebook-friends/facebook-friends';


@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: [FacebookFriends],
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class MyApp {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Platform]];
  }

  constructor(platform:Platform,facebookFriends:FacebookFriends) {
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;

    this.fb = facebookFriends;

    platform.ready().then(() => {

        this.fb.load().then((success)=>{
            if(success){
              console.log('success = ' + JSON.stringify(success));
            }
        },
        (error)=>{
            console.log('Error loading friends : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });


    });
  }
}
```

**My Provider:**

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

/*
  Generated class for the FacebookFriends provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class FacebookFriends {
  constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.data = null;
  }

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // We're using Angular Http provider to request the data,
      // then on the response it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
       var headers = new Headers();
                            // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                            this.http.post(
                                'http://192.168.1.45:3000/testrestapi',
                                {headers: headers}
                            ).map((res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
          // and save the data for later reference
          this.data = data;
      console.log('Friends Provider was a success!');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve(this.data);
        },
    (err)=>{
        console.log('Error in Friends Provider!');
    },
    ()=>{
           console.log('Friends Provider network call has ended!');
    });
    });
  }
}
```

**My page**:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {FacebookFriends} from '../../providers/facebook-friends/facebook-friends';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {

constructor(platform:Platform,facebookFriends:FacebookFriends) {
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;

    this.fb = facebookFriends;


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared service with a property of type Observable:

```
export class SharedService {
  dataReadyNotifier: Observer;
  dataReadyObservable: Observable;

  constructor() {
    this.dataReadyObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.dataReadyNotifier = observer;
    });
  }

  notifyDataReady(data) {
    this.dataReadyNotifier.next(data);
  }
}
```

When the data will there in the promise callback, the notifyDataReady method of the service would be called.

To be notified, components would register on the service observable this way:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.sharedService..dataReadyObservable.subscribe((data) => {
      // Do something with data
    });
  }

  (...)
}
```